# I can create a database in my Digital Ocean cluster, but why can't I connect to it

Tags: postgresql, ssl, digital-ocean, psql, tls1.3

I’m trying to deploy a Django app on Digital Ocean. I have an Ubuntu 22.04 server set up on a droplet and have just set up a managed database cluster with Digital Ocean and added a recommended connection pool. From the connection pool Connection Details, I select the VPC network connection (Droplet and Database Cluster are both in the same DO Project), choose the flags option, and copy the connection string to the droplet server.
This makes a successful connection. It gives me a message about the SSL connection like protocol (TLSv1.3), cipher, etc. It gives me a PSQL prompt and I successfully run a CREATE DATABASE command. I list the databases and see the database I just created. I then try to connect \c new_database_name;
and I get this error:

connection to server at "[database name from connection string].c.db.ondigitalocean.com" (10.x.x.x), port 25061 failed: FATAL:  no such database: [newly created database]

connection to server at "[database name from connection string].c.db.ondigitalocean.com" (10.x.x.x), port 25061 failed: FATAL:  SSL required

I've setup apps like this on private, internal networks but never on a public cloud. How can I connect from the server to the DB and make sure my app connects when it is installed? Any help would be appreciated.

Postgres v14.9, UFW is active.

Comment: have you tried with -d <database_name> option in psql commnad

Comment: Hello. Yes, I just attempted the connection string adding in the -d flag. A good suggestion, but it produced the exact same errors.

Comment: Does you database name have capital letters in it (or attempt to)?  Did you put it in double quotes while creating it?

Comment: My database name has all lowercase letters, an underscore, and some numbers. I did not have double or single quotes around the database name in the create statement.

Answer (score 0):

It was the recommended database connection pool. I deleted that, connected directly to the database and everythin proceeded as expected.